# Docker build on apt-get update fails

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

Docker fails to build from docker file with a symlink error message. Tried changing the images from python 2.7 to ubuntu:latest, but the issue persists. I am running Docker for Mac and stuck at this issue.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev && apt-get clean -y
ADD odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
ADD requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt
ADD . /opt/webapp/
WORKDIR /opt/webapp
CMD python server.py
```

Docker build command:
`docker build --no-cache .`

Docker build command output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 231.2 MB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> ca388cdb5ac1
Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tdsodbc unixodbc-dev && apt-get clean -y
symlink ../7e0c72321f41b854d5180eac25a4cad71bb8ce4dfed8b6f4b9f0b568a608013a-init/diff /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/D734HIV6BPIVR3LJZWGYVQZBKD: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Please describe your host environment incl Docker and OS version.

Comment: @KlausD. Docker version 1.13.1, macOS Sierra 10.12.3 stable. Does that help?

Comment: Have you restarted the docker daemon or rebooted your machine? Some people reported a similar problem with docker 0.12 that could be fixed by a restart. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27233

Comment: Yes, I did restart my daemon and also tried rebooting my machine, still no success, problem persists

Comment: **Problem solved, editing my question**

Comment: Usually you would add your own answer below.